# How wind patterns and ocean currents would be in a planet that does not rotates on its axis?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, climate

Imagine a world that does not rotate in its axis, the planet is not tidally locked so no half is hotter or colder than other. For example the planet does not rotate because it is in a binary sistem where the two gravital forces of the stars cancel each other, but could be any other reason.

In this bizarre planet, I assume the Coriolis effect would be zero so how would the wind pattern and ocean currents be affected?

Wainting for your responses! Thank you.

Comment: In that case the planet does rotate in relation to the star, it's just that a day lasts as long as a year.

Answer (score 4):

> Imagine a world that does not rotate in its axis, the planet is not tidally locked so no half is hotter or colder than other.

On average they won't be, but now the length of the day and that of the year will be the same. So, you'll have six "months" of darkness and six of daylight. During *those*, you will get cooling and warming. A lot of both, in fact. You will have air and water currents reflecting that.

Comment: With strongs winds and currents following the terminator...

Comment: I think Venus might be a good example where a (sideric) day is longer than a year. And you have quite some atmospheric activity there.